# CSHTML files not loading outside of Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a C# MVC Razor site. Typically, Controllers load views from the Views folder. However, I have a special circumstance where I need to render a view outside of the Views folder. How do I do that?

- Controller will load /Views/Random/Index.cshtml
- Can't load /Random/Index.cshtml
- /Random/test.aspx loads with no issues, but can't change cshtml files to aspx files, they need to be built regularly.

I have tried return Redirect("/Random/Index.cshtml") in the Controller, and currently have no controller at all.

The weird thing is it works on my Production environment, but not in localhost. In localhost I get:

> The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Random/Index.cshtml

Comment: _Why_ do you need that? What error does it give you?

Comment: Without the Contoller in place it says cshtml files have been explicitly forbidden. With the Controller it either causes an endless loop (when I use redirect) or it says the folder doesn't exist (which it doesn't inside the Views folder)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual, full error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return View("~/AnotherFolder/Index.cshtml")` should work for you.

Do not forget to indicate the Layout in your index view:

```
@{
   Layout="~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: This worked, except I had to add @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage at the top of the page. Also it's not loading any of the configs like bundle config. How do I get it to do that? Like I want it to load like a normal page in the View. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm , I do not have such problem, I think it should work like normal view,Did you indicate layout on your view?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just did exactly what you told me: return View("~/Random/Index.cshtml");

Comment: try to ad this in your view: @{Layout="~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";}

Answer (score 5):

You can definitely do this. For doing this you need to create one new custom view engine like

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private static string[] AdditionalViewLocations = new[]{
        "~/Random/{0}.cshtml"
    };

    public MyViewEngine()            
    {
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
        base.ViewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
        base.MasterLocationFormats = base.MasterLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then in you global.asax's Application_Start method register this view engine like this-

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine ());
```

If you want your viewengine to take precedence then insert this at 0th position. like this -

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new MyViewEngine());
```